# AM Charts : Chang to Persian date trendline instead of Gregorian date

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, amcharts

How can I use AM Charts with Persian (Shamsi) calendar in 'AM Charts trendline'  ?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/chart-with-persian-number-format/)?

Comment: No, I want to use 'Shamsi date' in trenldine.

Comment: Does it have Some Event like `Formatting`?

Comment: I want to use 'Persian(Shamsi) date' instead of Gregorian date In AM Line Chart with Scroll and Zoom and convert Gegorian to Persian(Shamsi) date.